# Mist 0.5.1 synchronization problem on Windows

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, mist, synchronization, windows

I'm running Mist on Windows 10. I have been trying to download the blockchain since yesterday and the process is too slow and cumbersome.
I switched off the firewall and I set the clock and I started the client. Although, when I start the client I reach 10-20 peers, this number drops, and most of the time is between 0-4. I set again the clock, but this does not improve. Thus, I restart the client. 
At moment 378093 blocks left.
Initially it was faster, now it seems to be very slow (< 25-100 blocks/min).
No special error in Geth, only when the peer number drops to 0, it appears a synchronization error.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

you might want to delete the whole chaindata folder `(C:\Users\$User$\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\chaindata)`

Then open geth using command line and enter `geth --fast`
Once synchronization is slowing (1 block at a time), start the wallet

Answer (score 1):

You will find a `geth.exe` executable in the `.\resources\node\geth\` subdirectory under your Ethereum Wallet installation directory. Here is the content of the Windows download package for Ethereum Wallet 0.5.2 showing the `geth.exe` executable:

```
user@Kumquat:~/Downloads$ unzip -tv Ethereum-Wallet-win64-0-5-2.zip 
Archive:  Ethereum-Wallet-win64-0-5-2.zip
    testing: Ethereum-Wallet-win64-0-5-2/   OK
    testing: Ethereum-Wallet-win64-0-5-2/AUTHORS   OK
    ...
    testing: Ethereum-Wallet-win64-0-5-2/resources/node/geth/geth.exe   OK
    ...
```

Delete the contents of the `chaindata` subdirectory from `%APPDATA%/Ethereum`.

From your Ethereum Wallet installation directory, run the command:

```
.\resources\node\geth\geth --fast console
```

You should see something like the following messages (I'm running in Linux):

```
I0408 17:21:39.549439   29822 flags.go:425] WARNING: No etherbase set and no accounts found as default
I0408 17:21:39.549604   29822 database.go:71] Alloted 16MB cache to /home/user/EthereumWallet/tmp/chaindata
I0408 17:21:39.719778   29822 database.go:71] Alloted 16MB cache to /home/user/EthereumWallet/tmp/dapp
I0408 17:21:39.721252   29822 backend.go:314] Protocol Versions: [63 62 61], Network Id: 1
I0408 17:21:39.721397   29822 backend.go:362] Blockchain DB Version: 3
I0408 17:21:39.721823   29822 blockchain.go:214] Last header: #0 [d4e56740…] TD=17179869184
I0408 17:21:39.721875   29822 blockchain.go:215] Last block: #0 [d4e56740…] TD=17179869184
I0408 17:21:39.721917   29822 blockchain.go:216] Fast block: #0 [d4e56740…] TD=17179869184
I0408 17:21:39.727628   29822 cmd.go:114] Starting Geth/v1.3.5-34b622a2/linux/go1.6
I0408 17:21:39.727768   29822 server.go:311] Starting Server
I0408 17:21:41.677719   29822 udp.go:212] Listening, enode://2b3f690e2c7c398d5782a5a33d47da9965cf08497299d3b232014fc89b0a8cbdc66d789110f0cb5a047d24aa4e1f9987ebdbcf88108aec035629d3af8b5faba4@[::]:30303
I0408 17:21:41.677903   29822 backend.go:526] Server started
I0408 17:21:41.678055   29822 server.go:552] Listening on [::]:30303
I0408 17:21:41.678340   29822 ipc.go:112] IPC service started (/home/user/EthereumWallet/tmp/geth.ipc)
instance: Geth/v1.3.5-34b622a2/linux/go1.6
 datadir: /home/user/.ethereum/
coinbase: null
at block: 0 (Thu, 01 Jan 1970 10:00:00 AEST)
modules: admin:1.0 db:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 shh:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0
> I0408 17:22:01.678243   29822 downloader.go:288] Block synchronisation started
I0408 17:22:06.973046   29822 blockchain.go:889] imported 192 header(s) (0 ignored) in 1.274319263s. #192 [88e96d45… / 723899e8…]
I0408 17:22:06.982296   29822 blockchain.go:1044] imported 2 receipt(s) (0 ignored) in 711.895µs. #2 [88e96d45… / b495a1d7…]
I0408 17:22:09.990297   29822 downloader.go:1102] Rolled back 192 headers (LH: 192->0, FB: 2->0, LB: 0->0)
I0408 17:22:11.778867   29822 blockchain.go:1044] imported 190 receipt(s) (0 ignored) in 36.573252ms. #192 [3d612266… / 723899e8…]
```

The last five lines of messages above show that geth is successfully connected to other peers on the Ethereum network and is downloading the blockchain data.